# Default element values of an array

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Pinescript v5:

- I was building a code to count the number of trades in a given candle.
- The logic I thought would be to count whenever there is a change in volume on a second's basis (since that is the lowest time frame accessible) as a crude proxy.
- The limitation is when volume changes more than 60 times within a second for very liquid securities, the maximum count would be 60 and it would remain constant for the rest of the day.
- However, I thought it could be useful when the volume changes less than 60 times in a second.
- I am not a programmer I could build this code:

```
float[] vol = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "S", volume)
len = array.size(vol)

plot(len)
```

- The script plots the values the total of which obviously won't match with the exchange provided Total Number of Trades. But it doesn't match even for securities where the volume was negligible. The values though are moving along with the actual volume.
- I have two questions -

  1. The code plots values even for securities with no volume data. What is this data? Are these the default values of `array.size()`? If yes, why are the values different for other securities with no volume?
  2. Could there be a better way to count change in volume on a second's basis?

Thanks much.